# What is the difference between "=" and "+=" in Python?

Tags: python, operators

What is the difference between `=` and `+=`?

I've been experimenting, and I haven't found the difference.

Comment: `+=` is a short notation for adding a value to the variable. Lets say if `x=1`, then `x += 1` will add 1 to x, so when you print x, it should say `2`

Comment: If you always  start with an empty / zero value then there is effectively no difference but I imagine if you started with anything else you would see the difference.

Comment: `x += 5` is the same as `x = x + 5`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't provided any examples that demonstrate your confusion. Without introducing non-standard classes (which you don't mention), the only case where `=` and `+=` would appear to be doing the same thing is if the variable on the left is already assigned to either `0`, `[]`, `{}`, or `''`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, the phrase `x=4` will assign the value of `4` to `x`.  However, the phrase `x+=4` will increment `4` to the current value of `x`.  For example:

```
x = 3
print x #will print 3
x += 2
print x #will print 5
```

Comment: Thanks; it makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 9):

Similar to many other languages, `+=` is a "shortcut".

```
x = y
```

Assigns a reference to the object on the right-hand-side to the name on the left.

```
x += y
```

Conceptually adds the object or the right-hand-size to the object referred to on the left.  Conceptually the same as:

```
x = x + y
```

I say "conceptually" because the `+=` operator can do different things depending on the class of the object on the left.  For example with an integer it simply does an add, with a string (`str`) it appends to the string, with a `list` it adds a new element to the right side of the list.

A class can implement the `__iadd__()` special function which will carry to the required operation.  `+=` is a member of *augmented assignments*, see http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/

Answer (score 0):

`foo = bar` sets `foo` to the same value as `bar`- if `foo` is 5 and `bar` is 3, `foo` is now 3.

`foo += bar` is shorthand for `foo = foo + bar`. So if `foo` is 5, and `bar` is 3, foo is now 8

This does in fact use whatever `+` means in context, so if `foo` is "A String" and `bar` is "bar", `foo += bar` makes `foo` == "A Stringbar"

Answer (score 0):

= is used to assign a value to a variable. e.g.: c=1+c (which assigns the value of c+1 to c, so it increments c by 1 )

+= is used to increment a variable by a specific value. e.g.: c+=1 (which

Answer (score 0):

`x = 4` initiates the variable `x` to equal 4

`x += 4` is actually `x = x + 4`. If you try to do `x += 4` without initializing x you will get a name error

```
y = 5  # 5
y += 2  # 7

x += 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

`x = 2` assigns a value `2` to the variable `x`. `x += 2` is the same as `x = x + 2`. In other words `+=` adds a value to a already existing value. Example:

```
>>> x += 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

This is because `x` has never been assigned to a value. To understand what happens, look at the following code:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> print(x)
2
>>> x += 2
>>> print(x)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

In python

`c = a + b` assigns value of a + b into c

`c = 1 + 3 #returns 4`

`c += a` is equivalent to c = c + a

`c = 1`
`a = 2`

`c += 1 #returns 3`

Check out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Notes:**

`a=b` : assign the value `b` to the variable `a`

`a+=b` : sum `b` to the current value of `a`

`a+=b` is a short notation for `a = a + b`

You can do `a-=b`, it'll reproduces `a = a - b`

you can either to `*=` , `/=` and `%=`

---

**Example:**

```
i = 2

i += 3
print i 
# output = 5 (2+3)

i -= 3
print i 
# output = 2 (5-3)

i *= 3
print i 
# output = 6 (2*3)

i /= 3
print i 
# output = 2 (6/3)

i %= 3
print i 
# output = 2 (modulo of 2/3 = 2)
```